# What about using a microkernel for Node.js + NginX?

Tags: nginx, node.js, microkernel

Not even sure if it would easily work but for an upcoming project I may need to set up a web sockets only server, it would not have a database, memcache or even serve static files, all it would need to do is work some logic and update other clients.

The server may need to support 1~300000 clients simultaneously so Node.js+NginX makes sense, but maybe not all the other features of a traditional web server (apache for example) are necessary...

Something like Minix sounds like it would work...

Comment: I was thinking about something similar, I am just not familiar with this low level programming. L4Re looks like a promising project for fast microkernels. https://github.com/kernkonzept As far as I understand these kernels contain only the code necassariy to work on a certain CPU architecture and one has to write for example the network drivers, GPU drivers, filesystems, etc. for them to work. Probably all of these are done and we just need to wrap them somehow to work with a microkernel, idk. As far as I understand the advantage would be performance and security compared to Linux.

Answer (score 0):

This may be exactly what you're looking for:

https://github.com/tmpvar/cluster-socket.io

It allows you to handle large amounts of requests across multiple node processes.

Remember you can always stop into [#node.js](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=node.js&uio=d4) and ask questions! Make sure to report back with your findings.

Comment: Thanks! I did try getting NodeJS to work in Minix3 but it simply did not work, worked with a couple of guys and there are too many unresolved dependencies and its just a pain... I will try other microkernels and see if I have better luck. Thanks for your reply!